# Why does this combinations Function outputs a certain length of set?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, probability

Ashamed to ask this one, but I am taking an edx course called 'Probability and Statistics in Data Science using Python' and one of the functions there is to create Combinations. It is below:

```py
def combinations(A,k):
    if k==1:
        return [{x} for x in A]
    sets = []
    for x in A:
        for y in combinations(A-{x},k=k-1):
            if {x}|y not in sets:
                sets.append({x}|y)
    return sets
```

Where  `A=set(range(1,5))`

So calling `combinations(A,2)` will return the following:`[{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}]`. And calling `combinations(A,3)` will return the following:  `[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}]`

***Question:***

As we are not defining the k anywhere, how does the function know which length of permutations to return within a given set?

I would expect once the `combinations` function is called in the for loop, and it sees that `k` is !=1 (and hence `y` is a NoneType as `combinations` does nothing when `k`!=1), while `x` iterates through A and gets appended yielding a long set with a length of `A`.

How are we getting set length equal to `k`?

Thank you!

***EDIT 1***

Recursive functions... clear. However, simplifying the function a little still don't quite understand the behavior (adding a few print statements to see what is subtractied from the set):

```
def permute(A):
if len(A)==1:
    return [tuple(A)]
permutations = []
for x in A:
    print(x)
    for y in permute(A-{x}):
        print(x,y)
        print(f'x = {x},y = {y},length = {len(A-{x})}, output = {(x,)+y}, tuple = {[tuple(A)]}')
        permutations.append((x,)+y)
return permutations

A = {1, 2, 3}

set(permute(A))


1
2
2 (3,)
x = 2,y = (3,),length = 1, output = (2, 3), tuple = [(2, 3)]
3
3 (2,)
x = 3,y = (2,),length = 1, output = (3, 2), tuple = [(2, 3)]
1 (2, 3)
x = 1,y = (2, 3),length = 2, output = (1, 2, 3), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
1 (3, 2)
x = 1,y = (3, 2),length = 2, output = (1, 3, 2), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
2
1
1 (3,)
x = 1,y = (3,),length = 1, output = (1, 3), tuple = [(1, 3)]
3
3 (1,)
x = 3,y = (1,),length = 1, output = (3, 1), tuple = [(1, 3)]
2 (1, 3)
x = 2,y = (1, 3),length = 2, output = (2, 1, 3), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
2 (3, 1)
x = 2,y = (3, 1),length = 2, output = (2, 3, 1), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
3
1
1 (2,)
x = 1,y = (2,),length = 1, output = (1, 2), tuple = [(1, 2)]
2
2 (1,)
x = 2,y = (1,),length = 1, output = (2, 1), tuple = [(1, 2)]
3 (1, 2)
x = 3,y = (1, 2),length = 2, output = (3, 1, 2), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
3 (2, 1)
x = 3,y = (2, 1),length = 2, output = (3, 2, 1), tuple = [(1, 2, 3)]
```

At the first iteration function takes 1 and should leave `y` with (2,3), yet what it does is goes back for the second iteration of x and takes 2, thus leaving `y` with only 3, and printing a tuple as the condition where `len(A)==1` is met. Why?

Lastly, how can `y` return 2 elements in this example if `y` is a `for loop` (hence should be returning one element after another)?

Comment: So: `As we are not defining the k anywhere`. Are you referring to the `k` which is the second parameter of `combinations`?

Comment: You are explicitly setting `k` when you *call* `combinations`. `combinations(A, n)` returns sets of size `n`.

Comment: The recursive call returns sets `y` of size `k - 1` that explicitly *exclude* some value `x`, so `{x} | y` is a set of size `k`.

Comment: Thank you @quamrana and @chepner for your comments. Adding EDIT 1 if you can find time to shed some light on the unenlightened. Was not familiar with recursive functions so `k` parameter confusion is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

since every time you make the recursive call, you do it using k-1 and then append it to the 'x' var